# Hibernate's session.connection Error: "Too many users"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am developing a Java web application using Hibernate, but there is a part of it where I want to use JDBC because I am creating look-up tables dynamically.

After a few minutes of using my web app I get this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Data source rejected establishment of
>   connection,  message from server: "Too
>   many connections"

I know that using session.connection() is deprecated but I just want to get the underlying JDBC connection. I experimented using the session.doWork() but the error still occurred as it had before.

Here is what the code looks like:

Domain Layer:

```
/**
 * Goes through the list of lookupTableAbstractions and persists each one
 * @param lookupData
 */
public void updateLookupValues( List<LookupTableAbstraction> lookupData )
{
    lookupTablesData.dropAllLookupTables(lookupData);

    lookupTablesData.createLookupTables(lookupData);

    for (LookupTableAbstraction lookupTable : lookupData)
        lookupTablesData.persistLookupTableValues(lookupTable);
}
```

Data Layer:

```
public LookupTableAbstraction getLookupTable( String tableName )
{
    LookupTableAbstraction lookupTable = new LookupTableAbstraction();

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

    String sqlQuery = "select value from " + tableName;

    List<String> lookupTableValues = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).list();

    session.close(); 

    lookupTable.setTableName(tableName);
    for (String value : lookupTableValues)
        lookupTable.addValue(value);

    return lookupTable;
}

/**
 * Persists the passed in lookup table.
 * The lookup table that is used is determine by
 * the tableName field of the passed in lookupTable
 * @param lookupTable
 */
public void persistLookupTableValues( LookupTableAbstraction lookupTable )
{
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = getJDBCConnectionFromHibernate(session);

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        String tableName = lookupTable.getTableName();
        for (String value : lookupTable.getValues() ) 
        {
            String sql = " insert into " + tableName + 
                         " (value) " +
                         " values " +
                         "('" + value + "')";

            System.out.println(sql);

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Exception(persistLookupTableValues): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        try {
            tx.commit();
            connection.close();
            session.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception(persistLookupTableValues): " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Drop's all lookup tables.
 * It drops each table based off the lookupTableAbstractions in the passed in list
 * @param lookupData
 */
public void dropAllLookupTables( List<LookupTableAbstraction> lookupData )
{
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = getJDBCConnectionFromHibernate(session);

        Statement stmt = null;
        for (LookupTableAbstraction lookupTableAbstraction : lookupData) {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("drop table " + lookupTableAbstraction.getTableName());
        }

        stmt.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Exception(dropAllLookupTables): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            tx.commit();
            connection.close();
            session.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception(dropAllLookupTables): " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates all lookup tables, one for each lookupTableAbstraction
 * in the passed in list
 * @param lookupData
 */
public void createLookupTables( List<LookupTableAbstraction> lookupData )
{
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = getJDBCConnectionFromHibernate(session);

        Statement stmt = null;
        for (LookupTableAbstraction lookupTableAbstraction : lookupData) {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("create table " + lookupTableAbstraction.getTableName() + 
                               " ( ID  int(11) auto_increment, " +
                               "  value text, " +
                               "  primary key (ID) )");
        }

        stmt.close();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Exception(createLookupTables): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            tx.commit();
            connection.close();
            session.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception(createLookupTables): " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected Connection getJDBCConnectionFromHibernate( Session session )
{
    return session.connection();
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: It would certainly seem that you are leaking connections somehow.  To verify this can you monitor the # of connections your application is using?  You can get this value from the session factory if statistics is enabled.  session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getConnectionCount().

Comment: Can you see any of exceptions you are logging in your code?

Comment: Hi Pace, 
I enabled statistics, and as I use the application it consistently stays at 1 connections.

Hi axtavt, The only exception that is thrown is when I get the "too many users" exception.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I don't know what could be causing the issue.  Do you know if  you're using a pooled connection provider?  It's possible the connection pool is simply set greater than MySQL allows (by default I think this is 100) and this misconfiguration isn't exposed until now.  Another way to debug the issue would be to download the Hibernate source and figure out what exactly is happening when you call Connection.close() (Connections returned by Hibernate are actually proxies and not the real underlying Connection)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. A lot of the examples on the internet forget to close out the session factory. If you don't close this out you will get the mysql "too many connections" error. Close it out with this line of code:

```
fact.close();
```

Assuming you named it *fact* like this:

```
SessionFactory fact = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem.

I was creating the session factory over and over.

So, I did this:

```
protected static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

static 
{
    sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
}

/**
 * Returns a Hibernate session factory
 * @return
 */
protected static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
{       
    return sessionFactory;
}
```